# Suite CRM - Add custom field in contacts subpanel of accounts detail page

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I wanted to create a 'Call Button' in the contacts sub panel of accounts details page. I could create 'Call button' in the contacts list page with logic hooks. But the same way of implementation is not working in the sub panel. (This button has no connection with the DB, it just trigger a JavaScript function when click on it.). Please help me on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the your contacts subpanel metadata file?

Comment: Sure.

The file call_button.php i kept in the /custom/modules/Contacts/metadata/subpanels

`<?php
$dictionary['Accounts']['fields']['call_button_c'] = array(
  'name'      => 'call_button_c',
  'vname'     => 'LBL_CALL_BUTTON_C',
  'type'      => 'varchar',
  'source'     => 'non-db',);

?>`




To add custom fields in contacts subpanel of accounts details page, we have to edit the 'Accounts' module only? Somewhere i found to edit the Contacts module.

Thanks

Comment: @DanielSamson Can you please explain the steps can be follow to implement this. There are three files in the '/modules/Accounts/metadata/subpanels' directory. default.php, ForEmails.php, ForProspectsLists.php. Is there any specific reason in the file names. If we make the subpanel folder in the custom directory, does it work? I'm a bit confused and new to CRM. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at modules/Contacts/metadata/subpanels/ForAccounts.php.

Why "ForAccounts"? It simply means that this Contacts sub panel will be loaded for the Accounts module. So that you can have different functionality for each module. **default** is simply the default sub panel used when a calling module is not specified. This is due to the way SuiteCRM handles relationships. You can specify in the relationship which subpanel should be displayed.

Notice the "top_buttons" array. These are the buttons at the top of the sub panel. The widget_class corresponds to the widgets in include/generic/SugarWidgets. Eg SubPanelTopCreateButton is actually SugarWidgetSubPanelTopCreateButton.

```
'top_buttons' => array(
    array('widget_class' => 'SubPanelTopCreateButton'),
    array('widget_class' => 'SubPanelTopSelectButton', 'popup_module' => 'Contacts'),
),
```

If you wish to add your own button you must first create your own widget and then add it to the top_buttons array.

The sub panels use the following to generate the buttons

- include/generic/LayoutManager.php
- include/SubPanel/SubPanel.php:120
- include/SubPanel/SubPanelTiles.php:426

You may have to register your widget with the layout manager.

SugarWidgets are a core feature and currently will not load from the custom directory.

Take a look at SugarWidgetSubPanelTopCreateTaskButton.php as a reference guide.

Comment: Thank you so much for your replay. I got an idea regarding the 'ForAccounts.php' and subpanel. But regarding the buttons i wanted to make the buttons in each rows. Let me try with this.

Comment: I have created 'ForAccounts.php' in '/custom/modules/Contacts/metadata/subpanels' there in the file, added the call button array (contents copied from 'subpanels/default.php'). Now if we go to the 'Admin->studio' and expand the 'Accounts->Subpanels->Contacts', the 'Call Button'is there in the default list. But it is not appear in the contacts subpanel of Accounts !. Thanks.

Comment: Once after i create the 'ForAccounts.php' and 'Quick Repair and Rebuild', a new file is created 'Account_subpanel_contacts.php'. Whenever i modifying the file, it reflects the subpanel lists.